# try-with-resources fails but try works

Tags: java, rabbitmq, try-catch, java-11, try-with-resources

I'm trying to set up a service which listens to a RabbitMQ server and I've set up code using the [RabbitMQ  Sample code from Github](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-tutorials/blob/master/java/NewTask.java), which includes the following `try-with-resources` block

```
try (Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
     Channel channel = connection.createChannel()) {
        // code here
}
```

When I use the same code and build and run this service using `java -cp myJar.jar MyService`, it just starts and ends immediately *(and `echo $?` returns 0)*

However, if I replace the block with the following, then it works fine with the same command, and I'm able to start a listener to a RabbitMQ instance

```
try {
     Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
     Channel channel = connection.createChannel());

     // code here
}
```

---

The same happens even when I create database connections

```
try (Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection()) {
    //code here
}
```

fails but

```
try {
    Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
    //code here
}
```

works fine, and allows me to use the connection to make entries into the DB as well.

---

Why is this happening? I'm using `OpenJDK 11.0.2` and this service is standalone, but the rest of the codebase is a JAX-RS driven Rest API if it helps.

Comment: It’s hard to believe that your code works with what you have posted, as a block like `try { … }` does not even compile.

Answer (score 5):

The try-with-resources construct closes the resources when the block exits. Your basic try block code doesn't close anything. That's the difference between the two.

When you use try-with-resources, you need to actually *DO* something with the resource.

If you're writing code where the resource you are opening needs to be 'long lived', then try-with-resources is not the right construct (though, generally, that means the class you're writing should itself be AutoClosable).

Answer (score 3):

When using *any* concept in programming you have to understand what you are doing!

The **whole point** of try-with-resource is that the resources are guaranteed to be closed when the try block ends.

But note: just using a try block is not sufficient. Such critical resources, like a database connection require distinct and intentional life cycle management. In other words: you should keep such resources around exactly as long as you need them. And you better make sure that you don't mistakenly forget to close a resource when it is no longer required!

Thus you should **not** lightheartedly give up on try-with-resource. Rather make sure that code that requires such a resource gets called within the scope of such a try-with-resource block!